# Subfigure alignment - want horizontal but coming up vertical

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to get the subfigures below to appear on the same line.

```
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{\columnwidth}
    %\centering
    \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.4555\textwidth]{histogram1.png}}
    %\caption{}
    \label{fig:histogram}
\end{subfigure}%

\hfil

\begin{subfigure}[t]{\columnwidth}
    %\centering
   \subfloat[h!][]{
   \begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}} \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{RESIDUAL STATISTICS} \\ \midrule
        Mean & 0.000000 \\
        Median & -0.33816 \\
        Maximum & 10.54783 \\
        Minimum & -3.60859 \\
        Std. Dev. & 2.147995 \\
        Skewness & 2.801059 \\
        Kurtosis & 12.82719 \\ \midrule
        Jarque-Bera & 1530.2** \\ \midrule
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\,\,\,* significant at 5\% level\\ ** significant at 1\% level\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}
    \end{tabular}
    }
    %\caption{} 
    \label{table:norm}
    }%\hfil
\end{subfigure}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4555\textwidth}
  \makeatletter
  \let\@makecaption=\old@makecaption
  \makeatother
  \caption{Blah blah blah}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure*}
```

This is how it appears with my code.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try to delete the blank lines before and after `\hfil`. If that does not help please make your code snippet compilable, then we can copy and test it on our own computers without guessing about used documentclass and packages ...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're combining `subfigure` and `\subfloat`.

Using also `siunitx` for aligning the figures.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\sisetup{table-align-text-post=false}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-4x3}
  \caption{}\label{fig:histogram}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l S[table-format=-1.6,]@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{RESIDUAL STATISTICS} \\
    \midrule
    Mean & 0.000000 \\
    Median & -0.33816 \\
    Maximum & 10.54783 \\
    Minimum & -3.60859 \\
    Std. Dev. & 2.147995 \\
    Skewness & 2.801059 \\
    Kurtosis & 12.82719 \\
    \midrule
    Jarque-Bera & {1530.2**} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\phantom{*}* significant at 5\% level}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{** significant at 1\% level}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{}\label{table:norm}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Blah blah blah}\label{generallabel}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[tl]{.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth, height=7cm]{histogram1.png}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[tr]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}} \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{RESIDUAL STATISTICS} \\ \midrule
        Mean & 0.000000 \\
        Median & -0.33816 \\
        Maximum & 10.54783 \\
        Minimum & -3.60859 \\
        Std. Dev. & 2.147995 \\
        Skewness & 2.801059 \\
        Kurtosis & 12.82719 \\ \midrule
        Jarque-Bera & 1530.2** \\ \midrule
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\,\,\,* significant at 5\% level\\ ** significant at 1\% level\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Histogram and Residual Statistics for \textit{rd}}
\label{figure:normality}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your given code compilable for a valid answer.